# Modifying OSX Server 10.5's DNS from the command-line

Tags: domain-name-system, command-line-interface, mac-osx-server

I'm trying to figure out how to add records to my server's DNS from the command-line. I've investigated the 'serveradmin' tool, plus 'scutil', but neither appear to give me access to modify the DNS records.

Anyone know how I might be able to do this?

Thanks

Comment: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050621051643993

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can do it with `serveradmin`, but the syntax is horrid.  The best way I know of is to edit the zone files directly (i.e. just append records to the end of them).  How the zone files are organized depends on the version of OS X server you're using:

Through 10.6, there were two sets: /var/named/db.zonename. and /var/named/zones/db.zonename.zone.apple.  The server admin interface manages the second files, so only add to them if you're adding record types it understands, and in the exact format it expects (and I mean *exact* -- I remember getting messed up once because I added records with the wrong number of spaces between fields).  You can add anything you want to the first set of files, as long as it's in proper `named` format (but it won't be visible in the admin interface).

Lion 10.7 keeps everything in a single set of zone files, /var/named/db/zonename.  I haven't experimented with it yet, but I'd assume you can at least add entries that the admin tools will understand.

Comment: From the documentation on serveradmin, it looks like it can turn the service on and off, but the PDF that I found (which was for 10.4 - I couldn't find the 10.5 one) didn't say anything about adding records. Adding them manually into the right file in /var/named/ looks perfect, though - thanks for that. I would vote you up, but as I'm new to ServerFault, I can't... Will mark you as the answer, though.

Comment: You can dump the DNS settings (including zone contents) with `sudo serveradmin settings dns >settingsfile`, edit settingsfile to include the new records, then use `sudo serveradmin settings dns <settingsfile` to load the changes.  If you look at the file, you'll see what I mean by horrible.

Comment: Wow - yeah - that's nasty... I think I'll stick with editing the files directly... Thanks!